# Stack Exchange Android App - What are the technologies and protocols used

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, android-app

I was wondering what is the architecture behind the Stack Exchange Android app. I was wanting to know what type of services are on the backend, what is the authentication principle being used, how are requests made to the database from the app.

I am trying to build my first app for Android, iOS and Windows phone. I was wanting to understand the market standard in doing so. Knowing about the Stack Exchange app would be a good start for me. I already have a WCF service that does all the business logic. I need to understand the ways to request information from a WCF service from Android, iOS or Windows Phone. Any guidance would be really helpful.

PS: I understand using jsonp calls to GET information from RESTful services and currently working on implementing that. Very important for me is dealing with very confidential information and thus securing the RESTful service.

Comment: Take a look at the [Stack Exchange API.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) Its a part of the whole.

Comment: @AsheeshR: Thank you for the link. The Stack Exchange API gives a very good idea of the app. Pretty much everything I expected, oAuth2 for authentication, json/jsonp responses. So, should I be safe in assuming this to be the market standard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the vast majority of the application is handled by the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). For authentication, we use OAuth, either by manually going through the flow stated in the documentation or using Android's built in ability to authorize using Google accounts, then sending those authorization keys to the server to trade them for a Stack Exchange auth_token.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since I am very new to all this, I was wanting to understand the complexity in setting up something like oAuth.