# Trouble finding my account details

Tags: support, android-app, user-accounts, account-recovery

I have the Stack Exchange app on my Android device for quite a while now,  and now I want to log into the same account on my Linux laptop.  The problem is that I don't know the email or password associated with it anymore.  I also don't know whether I used a Google account,  or if I made a Stack Exchange account,  or maybe even one of the other options.  I cannot seem to find any of that information in the app under settings or anything like that.

I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction to find out my account details so that I can log into the same account on my laptop.

Comment: Are you still logged in on the app?

Comment: FWIW The SE app [uses OAuth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225179/168333), so chances are that all it has is a "refresh token", and not the actual account info.

Comment: Hey,  yes it's logged in right now.  It's actually this account.  So ya,  any ideas how to get the info I need to log this account in from my computer? ?

Comment: Yes I wrote that one today as this one wasn't getting any more responses and I really wanted to log into here again on my pc